# Create new sheet with name from value of other sheet's cell's value

Tags: excel, vba

I have 02 sheets as follows. I want to add new sheets with name predetermined in "Sheet_Name" Column of Sheet " Summarize".

For example: I have entered 03 sheet name " ABC" , "BCC", "XYZ" then 03 sheets will be created with corresponding name. Then I will copy the content of the sheet "Template" to " ABC", "BCC", "XYZ" and change the B1 value of new sheets with its name.

How can I do this with VBA? I have written a snippet for creating but it can not run. Thanks.

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    n = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Summary).Range("B2", ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Count

    For i = 1 To n
        Sheets.Add
        Sheets.Add.Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Summary).Cells(i + 1, B).Value      
    Next i

End Sub
```

Sheet " Summarize"

[image]

Sheet "Template"
[image]

---

As per the guide of Bigben, I write these codes to create new sheets but apart from "ABC", "BCC", "XYZ", it created 03 other sheets.

[image]

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    With Sheets("Summary")
        n = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        For i = 1 To n
            Sheets.Add
            Sheets.Add.Name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out or remove the first `Sheets.Add`

Comment: It works. Thank you so much!